# How to correct for multiple post-hoc tests in multi-factor ANOVA

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

Let's for the sake of this question assume we did an ANOVA with three factors *A* (3 levels), *B* (4 levels), and *C* (5 levels). We get significant main effects for *A* and *B*.

In consequence we do three *t*-tests on *A*, and six *t*-tests on *B* (assuming these are the correct tests to perform in this case). Now, let's be conservative and do Bonferroni correction - what is the correct correction factor?

I can see two possibilities:

1. perform all tests with $\alpha/9$ (where 9 is the total number of tests performed)
2. perform the tests on factors *A* and *B* separately with $\alpha/3$ and $\alpha/6$, repsectively

Which - if any - of these is the correct procedure?

Surprisingly I found no succinct answer for this question on Google et al., but perhaps that is the wrong question for the answer I seek...

Comment: Well, I think people disagree. It comes down to this: Over what family of tests do you want to control the error rate? If it's all 9 tests, then divide by 9, if you consider them different families, then separate corrections. It's important to say clearly what you did when reporting. One nice thing about Bonferroni is that people can correct it their own way if they don't like the way you did it. I think it's kind of a can of worms, but I'm interested in others' comments too.

Comment: PS. To me, I'd be more concerned that you addressed the possibility that these factors may interact before getting into this other stuff . . .

Comment: Your comments make sense - as usual there is no one correct way. Often I find myself discussing with people who don't want to think about statistics. They want simple procedures and significant results :). I guess the best advice for them would be to test conservatively and report raw data and p-values? That way they are on the safe side, and anybody else who is interested can make up their own mind.